# How to pass a value from the TableView controller to a customCell class

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uicolor

I'm creating a custom UITableViewCell programmatically, which uses the following code. What im wondering is how to make the background of it Transparent?

Reason why I want it transparent is that the UITableViewCell's height is dynamic and i cant figure out how to pass the "dynamic height" code to the customCell class, so i figured i'd set a max height of 300 or so for the CGRect and make the background transparent so it doesn't overlap the following cells.

Making the label transparent doesn't work, so I need to pass the TableViewCell height to the custom class.

**customCell class**

```
#import "customCell.h"


@implementation customCell
@synthesize primaryLabel;
@synthesize secondaryLabel;
@synthesize priceLabel;

@synthesize rectColor;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self == [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code
        primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        primaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        secondaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        secondaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8];
        priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        priceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        priceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

        //self.rectColor = kDefaultRectColor;

        [self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:secondaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:priceLabel];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;
    //CGContextSetFillColor(context, [UIColor clearColor]);


    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+5 ,5, 200, 15);
    primaryLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+10 ,20, 300, 15);
    secondaryLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+270 ,0, 50, 15);
    priceLabel.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**UITableView Class**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [[[customCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; 
    }

    cell.primaryLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.primaryLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.primaryLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);
    cell.secondaryLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];
    cell.secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.secondaryLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);
    cell.priceLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *titleString = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *detailString = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];
    CGSize titleSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize detailSize = [detailString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return detailSize.height+titleSize.height;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean some cells have a different height but they never change _or_ do you want to make one cell's height change?

Answer (score 1):

If you make your table cells massive and transparent you're going to make the rendering fantastically slow!

I'd take a look at the [delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) - this method is how you tell a cell how high it should be.

Calling `[tabelView reloadData]` will cause this method to be called for each cell. Put your dynamic height code in there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yea i found that if i changed the

Comment: Im a total noob, are u able to be more specific or give me some keywords to look into? tyvm :)

Comment: In your table view delegate (probably your view controller) implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: - use this to tell your cells how high to be. Each time that you call realoadData, the table view will ask your view controller how tall to draw each cell.

Comment: yea my table cells are automatically dynamic height, i just dont know how to combine the two classes :S

Answer (score 0):

set the backgroundColor on the cell to be "[UIColor clearColor]"

Comment: cell.secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 - adding that made it clear but it still overlapped other cells(still). basically i got to figure out how to pass the dynamic height to the customCell class

Answer (score 0):

Because your row height is dependent on your custom cell layout (based on labels), I would put the sizing logic inside the custom cell class (in `layoutSubviews`) and in your `tableViewController` do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // initialize and configure your cell
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}
```

And I agree with the others that transparent cells should be avoided if possible.